# C# worker service vs windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, backgroundworker, service-worker

What is the big difference between the **worker service project template** and the **windows service project template** and which is better to use?

When can I use a worker service & windows service?

Comment: @DourHighArch: I'd assume that Dina is referring the [background tasks with hosted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) in **ASP.NET Core**. In **Visual Studio**, these can be created using the _Worker Service_ template.

Comment: @DourHighArch: Or, rather, **ASP.NET Core** or _any_ **.NET Core** application; they're not specific to **ASP.NET Core**.

Comment: And for completeness sake: Windows Service (as seen in Visual Studio project templates) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/introduction-to-windows-service-applications

Answer (score 34):

Both are real services.

**Windows Services** have existed for over 20 years. They start most often at system startup and run permanently.

A **Worker Service** is *also* a real process, but is intended as a background service for a front-end application; it starts with the application and stops with the application.

That said, a **Worker Service** can also be configured to run as a **Windows Service**.

So from a C# perspective, a worker service is the same idea as a Task or a Thread. But it runs in its own address and memory space. Therefore, it won't crash just because the application crashes.

Comment: I think the jury is still out as to what the OP means by _"worker service"_

Comment: Pretty sure threads _share_ the same memory space as the process.  Also, if the _"application crashes"_ the thread will end along with the process by definition

Comment: @MickyD You could just google. https://medium.com/@nickfane/introduction-to-worker-services-in-net-core-3-0-4bb3fc631225   And yes, a crash will finish a process, a thread is part of a process, it will end. What will not end, is a 2nd processes, started by the first one.

Comment: For apple cake you better take apples, for strawberry cake you take strawberrys. Depends on what you want to do. If you dont want to do anything, don't use it. You want to run something at machine startup or at application startup, might be the difference. A Windows service needs to be installed in the system registry, you have to be administrator etc. All that you don't need for just any background process.

Comment: really, I've not seen the difference between them.

Answer (score 4):

**Windows services**, formerly known as NT services, enable you to create long-running executable applications that run in their own Windows sessions. These services can be automatically started when the computer boots, can be paused and restarted, and do not show any user interface.
You can easily create services by creating an application that is installed as a service.

> [Refrence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/introduction-to-windows-service-applications)

**worker service** is a .NET project built using a template which supplies a few useful features that turn a regular console application into something more powerful. A worker service runs on top of the concept of a host, which maintains the lifetime of the application. The host also makes available some familiar features, such as dependency injection, logging and configuration.

> [Refrence](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/what-are-dotnet-worker-services)

### **Windows Service vs. Other Visual Studio Applications**

1. You cannot debug or run a service application by pressing F5 or F11
2. Unlike some types of projects, you must create installation components for service applications.
3. The Main method for your service application must issue the Run command for the services your project contains.
4. Windows Service applications run in a different window station than the interactive station of the logged-on user.
5. Windows service applications run in their own security context and are started before the user logs into the Windows computer on which they are installed. You should plan carefully what user account to run the service within.

Comment: Just to add, there is a framework called "TopShelf" (http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/index.html) that lets you develop Windows Service as a console app and easily install as a service without creating installation components. You can debug as usual in VS, step through the code, etc. Installing as a service is done by just typing the executable name with an argument of "install". I've used it for numerous projects (both framework and core) and it works very well.